# Is a key the same as a property?

Tags: javascript

As in, is "key" synonymous with property? if I do something like:

```
var foo ={
type:'x',
name:'y',
};
```

are both `type` and `name` keys and properties and is `x` and `y` the value?

Comment: The formal term is "property [name]", but "key" is used colloquially and is well-understood in context.

Answer (score 5):

A *property* refers to a name/value pair belonging to an object. According to the [ECMAScript spec 4.3.26](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-4.3.26):

> **property**
>
> association between a name and a value that is a part of an object

Each property *has* a name (to the left of the colon) and *has* a value (to the right of the colon).

In informal discussion about JavaScript, we sometimes use "key" to mean the name of a property. This commonplace usage is reflected in the existence of the function [`Object.keys`](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.2.3.14), which returns an array of property names belonging to an object. This use of "key" is borrowed from  computer science at large (as it applies to [associative arrays](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Associative_array)), not from the ECMAScript language specification that defines JavaScript, but surely virtually all JavaScript programmers would understand "key" to mean "property name".

Comment: More like `name/value` pair rather than `key/value` pair.

Comment: I would argue that "property name" is the official terminology (and is used through the specification), but "key" is implicitly acceptable in `Object.keys`. Good distinction between the property and the "key", however.

Comment: then why do people call these key/value pairs so often? Is it just convention?

Comment: Also since Objects in JS behaves *similiar* to a regular associate array, imo the term `key` is still acceptable and interchangeable.

Comment: @Derek朕會功夫 I was using "key/value" generally, but given the content of the question hinges on understand the use of the word, it is indeed a critical distinction. I'm revising now. It is worth noting that "key" shows up virtually never in the specification.

Comment: @apsillers Actually in Section 15.2.3.14 it refers property names as "keys", so I believe it's safe to say a *property* is a combination of a *key* and a *value*.

Comment: @prochine The computer-science concept of a "key/value pair" was around long before the existence of JavaScript. People call property names "keys" because that's what they *are*, according to the meaning of "key" within computer science.